# How to pass value between parent window and child window

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using Jsp, Structs. From a parent window (e.g)parent.jsp, I invokes child.jsp, which has a list of checkbox values. I select more than one values, then put it in a arraylist and send back to parent.jsp and store it in a textarea.

Now If i want to select some more values from child.jsp. When i again invokes child.jsp, the checkboxes i already checked will be checked there and i dont want the empty unchecked boxes.

Could someone help me in this.......If u send some sample code means its very useful.

Thanks in advance.....

Aadhira.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, when you go to the child.jsp for the second time you need to preserve the checked checkbox values. The only solution i see for this is pass these checked box parameters to the child.jsp form.

Comment: As I am new to this,could you please explain me with some sample code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not work in jsp. If your request is going through the server from parent.jsp to child.jsp, you need to pass the parameter from form(view) to controller(servlet i guess), accept the parameters from controller and pass it to the view(child.jsp). Try searching in google, you should get some helpful data from there.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable reply friend :)